# How to convert/encrypt WhatsApp .sqlite to .db.crypt8?

Tags: whatsapp-messenger, sqlite

I have aa WhatsApp ChatStorage.sqlite file which was taken from an iPhone backup, and I don't exactly understand the structure of the data inside the database, but it's clearly not encrypted.
I want to use this file to "restore" the messages it contains into a newer Android phone. From what I know the current format WhatsApp uses to store message databases is .db.crypt8 which I assume is the same SQLite DB, only encrypted (but I may be wrong). 
WhatsApp (2.12.317) on Android (5.0) doesn't seem to "recognize" the plain .sqlite file as a backed up DB on first setup. Is there a way to make it accept the file as a message backup? Can I somehow encrypt the DB file in the format it is expecting to receive?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok... at home now.

Don't know if you run unix variant or something else... That doesn't really but all these scripts have been run under Linux.

## create iphone backup (http://libimobiledevice.org)

idevicebackup2 backup

## Reading the backup

git clone https://github.com/PicciMario/iPhone-Backup-Analyzer-2
make build

## then modify main.py on line 1449

-database = sqlite3.connect(':memory:') # Create a database file in memory
+database = sqlite3.connect('/tmp/md.db') # Create a database file in memory

## then just start program and let it parse Manifest.mbdb of the iphone backup

python2.7 main.py

## parse /tmp/md.db and extract names of whatsapp files and media

sqlite3 /tmp/md.db
SQLite version 3.8.10.2 2015-05-20 18:17:19
Enter ".help" for usage hints.
sqlite> .mode csv
sqlite> .separator | \n
sqlite> .output files2.csv
sqlite> .headers on
sqlite> select fileid,domain_type,domain,file_path,file_name from indice   where domain = "net.whatsapp.WhatsApp" AND domain_type = "AppDomain";
sqlite> .out stdout
sqlite> .quit

## copy files and correct their names (just replace with your UUID):

foreach i (`cat files2.csv | grep Library/Media/ | grep '""' | sed "s/|\"\".\+$//g" | cut -d "|" -f 2- | sed "s/|/\//g"`);do;mkdir -p /tmp/extracted/$i;done

foreach i (`cat files2.csv | grep Library/Media/ | grep -v '""'  | sed "s/|/\//g" | sed "s/\/AppDomain/|AppDomain/"`);do;src=`echo $i | cut -d "|" -f 1`;dst=`echo $i | cut -d "|" -f 2 | sed "s/.$//g"` ; cp -v /Path/to/iphone/backup/UUID/0ef862e6faede9b72c75b948f8b5c9663921e796/$src /tmp/extracted/$dst;done

cp 0ef862e6faede9b72c75b948f8b5c9663921e796/ec50dd986a0f35953e40f6ca9602ad78173e254f /tmp/extracted/Contacts.sqlite

cp 0ef862e6faede9b72c75b948f8b5c9663921e796/7c7fba66680ef796b916b067077cc246adacf01d /tmp/extracted/ChatStorage.sqlite

## Now you have your whatsapp media and ChatStorage.sqlite

## install adb (from Android-sdk-update-manager) http://developer.android.com/sdk/

## On android install WhatsApp, become debugger and enable usb debugging. Setup WhatsApp and send at least one message and click backup in whatsapp. Download Legacy whatsapp and possibly also current one:

links https://github.com/AbinashBishoyi/WhatsApp-Key-DB-Extractor-UnOfficial/
wget 'http://www.whatsapp.com/android/current/WhatsApp.apk'

adb install -r -d LegacyWhatsApp.apk

## backup whatsapp (http://www.digitalinternals.com/security/).

## This is the only phase the legacy version needs to be installed:

adb backup -f whatsapp.ab -noapk com.whatsapp

## Extract key (http://www.digitalinternals.com/security/decrypt-whatsapp-crypt8-database-messages/419/):

dd if=whatsapp.ab bs=4096 skip=24 iflag=skip_bytes | openssl zlib -d > whatsapp.tar
tar xvf whatsapp.tar apps/com.whatsapp/db/msgstore.db apps/com.whatsapp/f/key
k=$(hexdump -ve '2/1 "%02x"' apps/com.whatsapp/f/key | cut -b 253-316)

## Pull whatsapp message backup

adb pull /sdcard/WhatsApp/Database/msgstore.db.crypt8 msgstore.db.crypt8

## decrypt:

iv=$(hexdump -n 67 -ve '2/1 "%02x"' msgstore.db.crypt8 | cut -b 103-134);dd if=msgstore.db.crypt8 bs=4096 skip=67 iflag=skip_bytes | openssl enc -aes-256-cbc -d -nosalt -bufsize 16384 -K $k -iv $iv | gunzip > msgstore.db

## merge databases (https://gist.github.com/paracycle/6107205). The script provided here is not complete and trou reading multiple forensicsites I now know how to modify, to get your media also... but that is work in progress

## Anyways:

sqlite3 -init ../convert.sql ../merged.db

## encrypt:

dd if=msgstore.db.crypt8 iflag=count_bytes count=67 of=msgstore.db.crypt8; cat merged.db | gzip -5 |openssl enc -aes-256-cbc -e -nosalt -bufsize 16384 -K $k -iv $iv | dd of=msgstore.db.crypt8 bs=4096 seek=67 oflag=seek_bytes conv=notrunc

## Push new backup:

adb push msgstore.db.crypt8 /sdcard/WhatsApp/Databases/

## Push current version back to android and start whatsapp to read the backup:

adb install -r -d WhatsApp.apk

Comment: Will still continue to work with this subject. Thinking of writing small C backend to automate this work... But don't probably have time to do it.

Comment: Wow, this looks very promising, I will give it a go when I get home.

Answer (score 0):

Well I've been doing the same thing for 2 days. It was relative simple. I have still not figured out how to include media.

Software you need:

Openssl
Adb (android debug bridge)
Sqlite3
legacy version whatsapp
+common unix tools

The work flow is like this:

Extract all media from iPhone backup. Filenames are hashed and indexes are in Manifest.mbdb and can be ten just copyed to right locations. With adb install legacy version of WhatsApp and retrieve key from android with adb backup. Uninstall legacy whatsapp. With adb download msgstore.db.crypt8 from android. Strip header and iv and decrypt with key and iv using openssl. Then gunzip and you have the msgstore.db

Merge msgstore.db with chatstorage.sqlite with standard SQL commands.

Gzip and encrypt msgstore.db using the same key and any iv. Store the header + the iv and the encrypted data in a file concatenated together and named msgstore.db.crypt8. Move the file to android /sdcard/WhatsApp/Database/ with adb and install WhatsApp.

I can I've you the sources but not at home rigth now.. So will do it later...

Comment: This sounds good. Can you maybe link to the required tools? Most importantly the legacy WhatsApp APK.